# Does testcafe support soft assertions

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, assertion, testcafe

I have a scenario that is an end to end testing where I have multiple assertion points. Observed that when an assertion fails test stops. But I need to just report a failed step in test results and proceed further with the test execution. Does Test cafe support soft assertions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. You might want to split your tests so that they test more specific things and not multiple assertions in a single test case.